# SSIS compare text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have two database DEV and TEST. I have sync some sp's from TEST to DEV.
Now i need to indentify which sp's are not sync in DEV database. last modified datetime is different in both database, so i can't use it.
In Sp i need to exclude multiple enter, space etc. (want to check sql code is same or not in SP).
How can i do this using SQL or SSIS

Comment: Or is it possible using .NET ?

Answer (score 0):

For compare database objects, you can use tools like this: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/

Comment: this one is good suggestion , but i can't install any third party tool. I can use SSIS, C# or sql only